# How well does backupexec work with Linux and archive format?

Tags: linux, backup, backupexec, netbackup

Having read [this server fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/22023/symantec-netbackup-vs-backup-exec-who-wins) , people said that Backup Exec's Linux support is not as good as Netbackup.

Has anyone had a good amount of experience with using backup exec with Linux, if so, how was it?

Also, for both Netbackup and Backup exec, does anyone know if the archive format is proprietary, or can something like GNU tar read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both NetBackup and Backup Exec use proprietary tape formats. I know that current versions of NetBackup can read the Backup Exec tape format, but AFAIK the converse (Backup Exec reading the NetBackup tape format) doesn't work.

I've only had a bit of experience with Backup Exec on Linux, so I'll leave my comments at: It backed-up the files we needed reliably. We never did a disaster recovery of any of the Linux machines that were covered strictly from tape. We opted, instead, to reinstall their OS and then restore data files from backup where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that BackupExec cannot read TAR tapes.

On the other hand, I have not hand any issues using the Linux/UNIX agent for BackupExec backing up Linux servers using BackupExec.  BackupExec uses it's own tape format.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success backing up / restoring files on linux with Backup Exec (v11+).  I can't speak to the other points of the questions.